# Swap class in elements in elements before 'current'

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs. One is marked as current. I need to swap an class in an element withing all divs preceding the current.

```
<div id="1">
    <span class="green"></span>
</div>

<div id="2">
    <span class="green"></span>
</div>

<div id="3" class="current">
    <span class="green"></span>
</div>

<div id="4">
    <span class="green"></span>
</div>
```

So, the 'green' class in divs with IDs 1 and 2 should change to 'red'. The class 'current' is changed when AJAX function returns different ID on success:

```
var ct = $('.current').attr('id');

$.ajax({
    ...
dataType: "json",

success: function(data){
    var cid = data.cid;

    if (ct != cid) {
        $('div').removeClass('current');
        $('div#'+cid).addClass('current');
    }
}
```

Not sure how to add that SPAN class swap. Do I add .each() for all spans? Then how do I stop once and don't change past 'current'?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect place to use jQuery's `lt()` selector. You have to extract the index of your `selected` div and then have an action on all elements that have an index less than the selected.

```
var selectedIndex = $("div.current").index();
var previousDivs = $("div:lt("+selectedIndex+")");
```

You now have a variable `previousDivs` which contain all the elements before your selected one.

References -

- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

Comment: I think that [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) is more suitable ;) Don't forget that the classes on the childs need to be swapped, and not the divs themselves.